# neo4j cypher select query in a tree-like structured graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to neo4j and cypher and trying to build the following query:
Select the nodes and the relations from the picture that are circled by the brown color (A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H and the relations) as the requirement is in the tree-like structure if I encounder a blue node I should add this node to the result but omit its children (related nodes). Relation directions are not important in this case.

Can you help me?

[image: diagram1]

[image: diagram2]

EDIT: And a second example is added. Again the required result are the nodes encircled **by the brown line**.

Comment: do you want the E node in the final list if E was connected to F

Comment: yes, as E will be also connected to B.

Comment: so , different color nodes have different labels or the color is a node property ?

Comment: @yanislavgalyov so you want all indirectly connected Leaves and Systems, as well as Elements connected directly to elements from that search?

Comment: @Nobody I added a second diagram. The starting point is node A and the result are nodes that expand from A and end in every blue node that is encountered. The required result of nodes is encircled by the brown line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the apoc documentation I found apoc.path.expandConfig function that almost solved my problem. 
So the solution is:

1. get paths to nodes that are Element or Leaf
2. get paths to system nodes
3. for path get relation return and return segment of the path as: (start)-[relationship]-(end)
4. union those segments to remove duplicates

It is working and my next task is to test performance with large graphs. Any thoughts? [@Nobody](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11948342/nobody) [@TheCrusher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12251717/thecrusher)

```
match (start: System) 
where id(start)=1
call apoc.path.expandConfig(start, { labelFilter: 'Element|Leaf' }) yield path
unwind relationships(path) as x
return startnode(x) as s, x as r, endnode(x) as e
union 
match (start: System) 
where id(start)=1
call apoc.path.expandConfig(start, { labelFilter: '>System' }) yield path
unwind relationships(path) as x
return startnode(x) as s, x as r, endnode(x) as e
```

EDIT: I came up with another query which does the work:

```
match (s: System)-[r*]-(m)
where id(s)=1 and (m:Element or m:Leaf or m:System) and not (s)-[*]-(:System)-[*]-(m)
unwind r as r1
with distinct r1 as rd
return startnode(rd), rd, endnode(rd)
```

Comment: for finding connected system nodes , its better to search for the system nodes which are connected to element/leaf nodes that are filtered in first expandConfig . because this will be small subset of relations compared all paths to all the connected system nodes from root system node.   will be very optimal performance wise

Comment: yes, I was thinking the same but couldn't come up with a good query.

Comment: i did like that in the query i shared .. did you try it ?

Comment: the second query will give wrong results . 
when a element node is connected to root node and is connected to system node . There is a possibility that this element node could not quality this pattern match ```not (s)-[*]-(:System)-[*]-(m)```

Answer (score 1):

```
MATCH p=(c:LabelSystem)-[r*]->(d) 
WHERE d:LabelLeaf OR d:LabelElement 
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT d) as labelElements,COLLECT(DISTINCT c) as labelSystem , c
MATCH (ls:LabelSystem)-[]-(le:LabelElement) 
WHERE le IN labelElements AND ls <> c
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT ls) as  childLabelSystems,labelSystem,labelElements,c.uniqueProperty as uniqueIdentifier
WITH labelElements+childLabelSystems+labelSystem as allNodes,uniqueIdentifier
RETURN uniqueIdentifier,allNodes
```

if you use color as property inside node, you can adjust WHERE accordingly

Comment: I will have to take my time and check this query but I am upvoting for the effort. Thank you. If this is correct I will mark it as an answer later.

Comment: I believe if we use WHERE d:LabelLeaf, we loose in performance, since we will go through each relationship to determine if we should pick it? Although might be good enough for given use case

Comment: since we needed to match with two types of nodes , we had to do like that . But cypher does it with label scan.its pretty fast enough :)